# Is there any reason why I should call Dispose() when using .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, dispose

I have recently taken over the responsibility for a code-base written using the .NET compact framework for mobile devices and I see the code scattered with `Dispose()` calls all over the place.

This seems to be on

- ADO.NET db commands
- Windows Forms

I thought that the Garbage collector would handle memory management. I know they might hang in memory a little longer without `Dispose()`, but is there much advantage or gain to having these calls?  It seems to pollute the neatness of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know they might hang in memory a little longer without Dispose(), but is there much advantage or gain to having these calls? I

It really depends a lot on *what* is being Disposed by these calls.  `IDisposable` isn't (necessarily) about releasing memory, but rather about releasing resources.  In general, you always should call Dispose on objects when it's possible to do so without huge hoops in your logic, and not rely upon the GC to cleanup resources unless necessary.

Given that you're running on CF, it's likely even more critical.  If your program is targeting a platform with limited resources, cleaning up those resources as soon as possible is very important.

Comment: That's what I thought. Do you think the code could be improved using 'Using' rather than the dispose calls?

Comment: @jaffa In many cases, yes.  A using statement is typically a safer, and cleaner, way to write code that uses types which are disposable, provided you aren't storing them between methods.  (It really only works if you create and dispose of the object in the same method...)  There's likely a lot of room for improvement in the code if Dispose() is called explicitly, but it's still a good idea to call Dispose via some mechanism.

Comment: I wouldn't use using if I had more than one object to dispose. Nested blocks becomes ugly fast. For example, if I were creating 4-5 GDI objects, I'd just create them all at the top of the method, and dispose them all at the bottom. But anyway, he's right, do not rely on the GC if at all possible not to. First of all the GC can't handle releasing resources that Dispose does (unmanaged resources). The only reason it **does** is because the Dispose **pattern** says that developers should call Dispose from the Finalizer which is called from the GC. If a developer didn't do that, you'd leak memory

Comment: @Alan I still prefer using to manual dispose, even if it's multiple objects, if it's all in a single method.  The main advantage with `using` is that you're guaranteed to release the resources even in the case of an exception.  You can stack using statements and only create one block, so it's not much larger than a normal declaration.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Are you sure about stacking Using statements? I believe I've done that with fixed statements, but using statements I believe are non-orthogonal and do not allow the use of "using" without a code block

Comment: @ReedCopsey Alright, I just checked and it does seem to work.. I wonder what I was thinking of that didn't allow it.... But yes I did know about the exception handling and that is a good point if exceptions can be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Typically,but not always, a call to Dispose is to release unmanaged resources. As a good practice, Dispose should be called for any type which has a Dispose methed.

Comment: Yes but ADO.NET and Forms ARE managed, yet the Dispose calls are still present.

Comment: Remember that under many managed objects there are calls to unmanaged code which needs to be dealt with. Also, calling dispose is an early message to the garbage collector that an object may be collected.

Comment: A good example here for a `Form` is to realize that internally it probably is doing Win32 API calls and holding onto pointers to memory locations that represent the window, etc... those things are unmanaged and therefore need to be released. The `IDisposable` interface provides a way to ensure `GC` will run the right code to release unmanaged resources when it cleans up the managed object.

Comment: Yep, couldn't agree more. If there are forms in the code I'm not au fait with I'll always call dispose in case there is a custom paint method etc. Many GDIs object have to be disposed manually. Simply put, if the developer has exposed a dispose method in an object you're using it would be daft not to use it.

Comment: A call to `Dispose` is to release resources.  Managed resources which are not `Dispose`d before all references are abandoned will generally be released *eventually*, but unless the resources in question are both fungible and plentiful, such release may not always be timely enough to be useful.  While there are occasions when one need not (or, with some poorly-designed classes, must not) use `Dispose`, one should always use `Dispose` *absent a good reason not to*.

Answer (score 0):

.NET calls `Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects... i.e. when `GC` cleans up a managed `IDisposable` object, it calls `Dispose()` which cleans up any unmanaged resources that the object uses....in which case, the main thing calling `Dispose()` seems to accomplish is a more deterministic releasing of unmanaged resources (because .NET doesn't use reference counters, an unreachable object may still exist and be using memory, and conversely, an object may be disposed by still be accessible).